# Place of backward and its relation with batches in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, pytorch

I am implementing a dependency parsing model using PyTorch and little bit confused about the situation that I explained below. When calculating loss and backward the model; I tried different things.

- When I use the code below exactly, and make batch size 1 (1 batch in iteration):

  - Loss looks like decreasing, however the predictions are not getting well after 20 epochs.
- When I use the code below exactly, and make batch size 100(0):

  - I get an error: `RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.`
  - As the error message said, when I use inside_loss.backward(retain_graph=True) instead of inside_loss.backward(), the execution tooks too long. (I did not get result yet)
- When I comment out the inside_loss and uncomment the lines after the for loop:

  - The loss is not changing.

The code is here:

```
def forward(self, x,):
# x is the scores of my vocab. It has grad so cannot change its values.
# So take the clone
x_prime = x.clone()

# loss = Variable(torch.zeros(1), requires_grad=True)
loss_v = torch.zeros(1)

for i in range(x_prime.size(0)):

    # Some operations that changes x_prime's values
    # Calculate sentence_probs and sentence_scores from x_prime's values

    eisner_values = eisner_torch(sentence_probs)

    # Changed x_prime above; so update the x
    x = x_prime

    # Get the gold dependencies
    gold_deps = return_gold_deps(i, sentence_to_dependencies)

    if gold_deps is None:
        continue

    mask = np.greater(np.asarray(eisner_values), -1)

    # Calculate hinge loss
    inside_loss = hinge(sentence_scores, eisner_values, gold_deps, mask, 1)

    # Calculate total loss in the batch
    loss_v += inside_loss.data

    inside_loss.backward()

    # Optimizer step
    if self.opt is not None:
        self.opt.step()
        self.opt.optimizer.zero_grad()

# loss.data = loss_v.data
# loss.backward()
# Optimizer Step
return loss_v
```

I use the Adam optimizer for this task:

```
model_opt = NoamOpt(model_size=d_model, factor=1, warmup=200,
                torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9))
```

What are the problems in here? How can I solve that issue?

Thanks in advance.

Link to stackoverflow: [Question also asked in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418724/place-of-backward-and-its-relation-with-batches-in-pytorch)

Comment: May I know what the outer loss means for your case? It seems not connected to anything? To add-on maybe what kind of behaviour do you expect (e.g. use the last optimized weight with another output neuron)?

Comment: @Yohanes The returned one for understanding changing in loss values and the commented one is for nothing, just for try and it is meaningless to me, too :)

Comment: My predictions are based on the values in 'x' variable, so I want to decrease the loss while improve my predictions, so improving values in x.

Comment: i understand the inside loss but I still don't get why would you need the outside loss (the 'loss' variable). I mean if it is not necessary why keep it there? Is it purely for viewing?

Comment: Yeap, I add them for the question's third bullet. But, I wrote them both up and down, I deleted one of them. This is just a comment line, my actual code is with the lines that is not commented out.